# Redirect all request to controller php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I was thinking about routing engine in my project, and im trying for some weeks to redirect all queries by single htaccess, which in the root dir, but when im trying to open directory that already exists, i have to add in each denied folder access rules. So the question is :

*Can i by usual htaccess catch all request to all folders, and give access only throught controller file?*

> Ps sorry for my Engl:)

Comment: Consider posting more information like, your .htaccess file, php script, etc Try Googling? http://jrgns.net/redirect_request_to_index

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all requests through to a single file use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first line stop the request routing to index.php if the request matches an existing directory and the second line does the same is a filename matches the request

If you want to just route all requests, regardless of other whether and file or directory exists that matched the request, just remove the first 2 lines

Comment: That doest works for directries in folders, i was trying all what i googled, and nothing works for dir